# How to display enum description or name in a grid row?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using the Kendo grid in my ASP.Net MVC application. If I have the following grid definition,

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model) //Bind the grid to ViewBag.Products
  .Name("grid")
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
      columns.Bound(p => p.FullName);
      columns.Bound(p => p.MyEnum)
  })
  .Groupable()
  .Pageable()
  .Sortable()
  .Scrollable(scr => scr.Height(600))
  .Filterable()
  )
```

where one of the column is an Enum. My enum definition is:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    [Display(AutoGenerateField = false, Name = "My enum 1", Description = "My Enum 1")]
    EnumOne,
    [Display(Name = "My Enum 2")]
    EnumTwo
}
```

How do I make it display "My Enum 1" or "My Enum 2" for each row?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

I recently ran into this problem and solved it by using

```
var someArrayOfValueAndText = new[] {new  {
    Id = 0, Description = "Foo"
}, new  {
    Id = 1, Description = "Bar"
}
.Columns(c.ForeignKey(m=> m.MyEnum, someArrayOfValueAndText, "Id","Description"))
```

instead of the .Bound method

Comment: Where do you put the array declaration?

Comment: This does not work if you need the grid to be exportable. JS functions are not called and just the data is exported.

Answer (score 2):

I created an helper class containing some extension methods a while back:

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static string GetDisplayName(this Enum enu)
    {
        var attr = GetDisplayAttribute(enu);
        return attr != null ? attr.Name : enu.ToString();
    }

    public static string GetDescription(this Enum enu)
    {
        var attr = GetDisplayAttribute(enu);
        return attr != null ? attr.Description : enu.ToString();
    }

    private static DisplayAttribute GetDisplayAttribute(object value)
    {
        Type type = value.GetType();
        if (!type.IsEnum)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Type {0} is not an enum", type));
        }

        // Get the enum field.
        var field = type.GetField(value.ToString());
        return field == null ? null : field.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>();
    }
}
```

It contains two methods for extracting the `Name` and `Description` of a `Display` attribute. The display name:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.MyEnum.GetDisplayName())
```

And for a description:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.MyEnum.GetDescription())
```

You have to add a using statement in your `Web.config` or in your view.

**Update**

What if you create a property for it in your model:

```
public string MyEnumName
{
    get { return MyEnum.GetDisplayName(); }
}
```

Now you should be able to use:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.MyEnumName);
```

Comment: I tried the above and got an error when I ran the application. The error is "Bound columns require a field or property access expression.". Thanks for your quick reply!

Comment: If I bind it like above, doesn't it mean that I can't use the grid's filtering capability? Currently, since it is bound to an actual Enum, I get a combo box that contains all the different enum values to select from in the filter menu.

Comment: @wm_ filtering will indeed not work anymore. Perhaps the Kendo grid offers some features to customize the data in cells? I have no experience with it. I'm sorry.

Comment: No worries. Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

Henk's solution is good. But you can use filtering capability if you use ClientTemplate:

```
col.Bound(m => m.MyEnum)              // this provides you filtering
   .ClientTemplate("#: MyEnumName #") // this shows a name of enum
```

For more information about kendo ui templates see: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview

Comment: Perfect. Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I use @user1967246 method and would like to explain more how to i do.

i created array in top of my kendo grid

```
    var statusLikeEntityStatus = new[]
    {
        new {Id = 0, Status = EntityStatus.Passive},
        new {Id = 1, Status = EntityStatus.Active},
        new {Id = 2, Status = EntityStatus.Draft},
        new {Id = 3, Status = EntityStatus.ReadyToLive},
        new {Id = -1, Status = EntityStatus.Freezed},
        new {Id = -2, Status = EntityStatus.Blocked}
    };
```

Then i use ForeignKey property instead of Bound.

```
     columns.ForeignKey(m => m.Status, statusLikeEntityStatus, "Id", "Status").Title(Resources.General.Status);
```

Here is my columns attribute

```
.Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(m => m.InventoryID).Title("Id");
          columns.Bound(m => m.ERPCode).Title(Resources.Products.ProductCode);
          columns.Bound(m => m.Price).Title(Resources.Products.ListPrice);
          columns.Bound(m => m.Discount).Title(Resources.Products.
          columns.Bound(m => m.Stock).Title(Resources.Products.TotalStock); // todo: Resources
          columns.ForeignKey(m => m.Status, statusLikeEntityStatus, "Id", "Status").Title(Resources.General.Status);

          columns.Command(commandConf =>
          {
              commandConf.Edit();
              commandConf.Destroy();
          });
      })
```

Hope it will help to you.